# can't see Outlook folder from mfcmapi

Tags: outlook, mapi

I'm using MFCMAPI to try to view some properties of a folder (named 'test') that's in my Outlook 2007 mailbox. However, when I go quickstart > open folder in the menu, I don't see my folder listed. Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: Do you see the folder in OutlookSpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu in the screenshot only shows the most frequently accessed folders. To see other folders, double click on the store, then click on the tree view to open a partiocular folder.

Comment: Thanks. Double-clicked on the store and then from the tree: root container > top of information store

Comment: Not “frequently accessed”. More like “folders Steve felt like hardcoding”. User created folders would never appear in that list.